# draw texture with polygon shape

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

I am trying to draw the texture with polygon shape.  What is the logic and how will i draw texture in polygon shape with dynamically?

I am working on cutting the rectangle, going to apply the texture in sliced shape(it may any shape).

Can any one assist me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't think you can achieve it only using cocos2d classes. You need to draw with openGL. You already have polygon vertices, triangulate your polygon([here is an example](http://www.flipcode.com/archives/Efficient_Polygon_Triangulation.shtml)) and set your texture to draw it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use LevelHelper (unfortunatelly - not free :( ) which has a built-in cutting engine : [link](http://www.gamedevhelper.com/levelhelper/)